# How to define an instance in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I see this line of code

```
CtvDfpAd.GetInstance = function () {
    if (!CtvDfpAd.__instance) {
        CtvDfpAd.__instance = new CtvDfpAd();
    }

    return CtvDfpAd.__instance;
};
```

is "instance" a keyword in javascript? i searched online, i don't believe it is, can someone explain?

Thanks

Comment: `__instance` is a property on CtvDfpAd.

Comment: Jesus! I think I've found a new keyword! Lol. +1 for making me laugh ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, __instance is not a keyword. The double-underscore prefix appears to be a convention to treat the member variable as private, since JavaScript has no concept of private variables.

This code is an implementation of the Singleton pattern in JavaScript. A singleton class means that it is designed to have only one instance throughout the lifetime of the program. This function checks if the instance exists - if it does, it returns it. Otherwise it creates one and returns the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is a keyword in JavaScript. Apart from that, it's a technical term in object-oriented programming. The code you posted uses a common pattern for instantiating objects

Answer (score 1):

Looks like instance is just a protected property of that CtvDfpAd object. Looks like it might be a singleton based on the pattern exhibited here:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

You'll almost certainly get a better idea of what that code is doing by reading that article, but in short, what this code is doing:

- If there is already an instance of our singleton, return it.
- Otherwise create a new instance of this object and return that.